# C# Inheritance of lists of interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm a bit new to C# interfaces, and have run into a rather awkward solution to an extension method on inherited interface lists problem. Example interfaces look like this:

```
public interface IData
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataWithName : IData
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataContainer
{
    IList<IData> DataList { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataWithNameContainer : IDataContainer
{
    new IList<IDataWithName> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

With an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static int CountNumberOfIDataItems(this IDataContainer i)
    {
        return i.DataList.Count();
    }
}
```

When implementing these interfaces, both the IList DataList and IList IDataContainer.DataList need to be implemented. While this is possible, the resulting code is inelegant:

```
public class DataNameImplimentatioFixed : IDataWithNameContainer
{
    public IList<IDataWithName> DataList { get; set; }
    IList<IData> IDataContainer.DataList
    {
        get => new List<IData>(DataList);
        set
        {
            DataList = new List<IDataWithName>();
            foreach (IDataWithName _dataLoop in value) { DataList.Add(_dataLoop); }
        }
    }
}
```

Duplicating the list each time that the extension is called could lead to some  performance problems, as well as needing an additional check that any further methods on IDataContainer won't try to add classes that inherit from IData but not IDataWithName.

It feels like there should be a better way of using the extension methods, that isn't as vulnerable to problems with future extensions. The best solution I can some up with is to take the IList DataList out of IDataContainer, and have a separate extension method for each class that contains a list.

Can anyone come up with a better solution than this?

Comment: Extension methods aren't part of the interface or class so inheritance doesn't apply. *Your* question though has to do with *hiding* `DataList` in IDataWithNameContainer. This has nothing to do with extension methods, it's a problem with the design that uses the same member names in related interfaces

Comment: This could be solved by making both container interfaces generic and using a stricter type constraint in IDataWithNameContainer

Comment: Good point on the the extension methods just being where the problem was showing up, not where it was located. I'll take out that from the tags & title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `IDataWithNameContainer` hides the `DataList` property it inherits from `IDataContainer`, not the extension method. It shouldn't do so.

The easy way to create a derived container class that only accepts a specific IData implementation is to make the container interfaces generic and use a stricter type constraint in `IDataWithNameContainer` :

```
public interface IData
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataWithName : IData
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataContainer<T> where T:IData
{
    IList<T> DataList { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataWithNameContainer<T> : IDataContainer<T> where T:IDataWithName
{

}

public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static int CountNumberOfIDataItems<T>(this IDataContainer<T> i) where T:IData
    {
        return i.DataList.Count;
    }
}
```

Creating a named container this way is easy :

```
public class Boo:IDataWithName 
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class BooContainer: IDataWithNameContainer<Boo>
{
    public IList<Boo> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

There's no reason to add new items to the `DataList` in a loop by the way. The `List` constructor can accept an IEnumerable with the initial values:

```
public class BooContainer: IDataWithNameContainer<Boo>
{
    IList<Boo> _list=new List<Boo>();
    public IList<Boo> DataList 
    { 
        get => _list; 
        set => _list=new List<Boo>(value); 
    }
}
```

This allows storing both lists and arrays to `DataList` by copying their contents into a new List.

This will throw if someone sets a null. To avoid this, one can use the null replacement operator in the setter :

```
    set => _list=new List<Boo>(value ?? new Boo[0]);
```

Comment: I think that's what I was after! It was hiding the list that was the problem, and getting the container interfaces typed will be easy enough in the code I hit this problem in.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `IDataContainer` and `IDataWithNameContainer`.  You already have the values in the `IDataWithName` interface so why is `IDataWithNameContainer` also inheriting from `IDataContainer`?  Isn't that why you made the extra interface?

```
IData
IDataWithName : IData
IList<IDataWithName>  //This already has a list of (name) and (value)
```

Simply make your class like so:

```
public interface IDataWithNameContainer // Do not add this here -> : IDataContainer
{
    IList<IDataWithName> DataList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: IDataWithNameContainer inherits from IDataContainer probably for the same reason IList inherits from IEnumerable. Because they refer to different things (behaviour, contents). In this case "different" means they should contain items that implement *specific* interfaces, probably because the container depends on them.

Comment: In any case, `new IList<IDataWithName> DataList { get; set; }` will raise a compiler warning

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not what I'm getting at.  One if the interface for the value and the other for the name and value together.  Why would he want two lists of the value, named the same, with the same interface?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And you're correct.  I didn't intend to leave the `new` in the fix.  I've updated it.